# Save as DictionarySectionHandler to App.config file

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration, app-config

I have several sections on my App.config file, saved as DictionarySectionHandlers. I can easily read them by casting them to a hashtable. Now, what I want, is to also be able to save a hashtable/dictionary as a DictionarySectionHandler, back to the App.config file. How is that possible?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx 

in the example look under AddUpdateAppSettings(string key, string value) 

this may help you get closer to what you need.

Comment: This is about saving to the appSettings section. Mine is a custom one which contains all the DictionarySectionHandlers.